# How to change size of svg cursor with angularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically change the size of the cursor over a canvas element based on the slider input.

My Cursor:

`cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg width='50' height='50' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3C!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ --%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cfilter height='200%25' width='200%25' y='-50%25' x='-50%25' id='svg_1_blur'%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='0' in='SourceGraphic'/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctitle%3Ebackground%3C/title%3E%3Crect fill='none' id='canvas_background' height='52' width='52' y='-1' x='-1'/%3E%3Cg display='none' overflow='visible' y='0' x='0' height='100%25' width='100%25' id='canvasGrid'%3E%3Crect fill='url(%23gridpattern)' stroke-width='0' y='1' x='1' height='400' width='128'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctitle%3ELayer 1%3C/title%3E%3Cellipse stroke='%23000' filter='url(%23svg_1_blur)' opacity='0.5' ry='25' rx='25' id='svg_1' cy='25' cx='25' stroke-width='0' fill='%23ff0000'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E") 25 25, auto;`

This is what I tried to do:

```
$scope.changeCursor = function(){
    var cursor = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    document.querySelector('#canvas').setAttribute('style', 'cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg width='+ $scope.options.brushSize +' height=' + $scope.options.brushSize + ' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%3E%3C!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ --%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cfilter height="200%25" width="200%25" y="-50%25" x="-50%25" id="svg_1_blur"%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0" in="SourceGraphic"/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctitle%3Ebackground%3C/title%3E%3Crect fill="none" id="canvas_background" height="50" width="50" y="-1" x="-1"/%3E%3Cg display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%25" width="100%25" id="canvasGrid"%3E%3Crect fill="url(%23gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="1" x="1" height="400" width="128"/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctitle%3ELayer 1%3C/title%3E%3Cellipse stroke="%23000" filter="url(%23svg_1_blur)" opacity="0.5" ry="25" rx="25" id="svg_1" cy="25" cx="25" stroke-width="0" fill="%23ff0000"/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E") 25 25, auto;');
}
```

Is there a way of doing this with ng-style?

Comment: Why don't you use variables for that?

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Use variables in your `cursor` instead of hardcoded values. Bind them and change as much as needed. For example, `[height]="height"`.